# Fastest stabilization time of a system of n integrators.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control

Given a set $n$ integrators of the form
$$\begin{align}
\dot x_i &= x_{i+1}\\
\dot x_n &= u
\end{align}$$
for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$, with nonzero initial conditions $x_0$, is it possible to determine the fastest time the system could be stabilized to origin, or even in a ball around it, while having the states remain inside a chosen closed set? And if yes, is an analytic solution/method possible, or would the results have to be numerical? By searching through optimal control bibliography, I've started leaning towards the latter. Keep in mind that the input is not constrained.

Comment: With the unconstrained input the problem is singular. For example, for one integrator only $\dot x=u$ the optimal input would be the delta-function at zero $u(t)=-x_0\delta(t)$ and the fastest time is zero. Similar thing happens in general: it is possible to construct explicitly the sequence of inputs that make the stabilization time go to zero. The sequence is unbounded.

Comment: @A.Γ. Then, what if you attempt to minimize  $J = \int_0^T u^2 dt$, or even better $J = \int_0^T (1+u^2) dt$, to include the time?

Comment: Then it becomes the LQR control problem. You can formally include the time as a new state variable with $\dot x=1$.

Comment: @A.Γ. How would you ensure that the states remain inside a closed set of choice though?